# Preventing FB from posting the wrong thumbnail

Tags: facebook, drupal, thumbnails

So I am running a Drupal site, and it has an image as its header. Now the problem is that FB *always* selects that one as a thumbnail for FB likes. This has become quite annoying because every like of a photograph is shown as the header of the site rather than the photograph itself.

I wondered whether anyone knew a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the og:image meta tag on the page.

Comment: Since it is a drupal site, I cannot manually change every og:image on every page. I just need to find a way so that the 'auto select' of FB's api doesn't sleect the header.

Comment: The only way to do so is to specify the correct og:image tag in the head section of the HTML, otherwise Facebook will pick one for you.

Comment: I am sorry, but it didn't. Since it is a CMS, I can't afford to put time in specifying the og-meta-tag for every single page I generate. So I want FB to skip the header images and search for images in the content area, rather than the header.

Comment: Can't be done.  You need to follow the open graph protocol. See ogp.me for more information on what Facebook is implementing.  Pretty cool that they don't do like Microsoft and create their own off-standard implementation of things that should be open.